# ReactJS: TypeError: this.state.myText.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typeerror

I'm trying to pass the index of an array's element to a function, during the process I'm getting the error: **TypeError: this state.myText.map is not a function**

This is my sourcecode:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ValidateText from './ValidateText';
import CharText from './CharText.js'
import './hwork02.css';

/* general purpose:
1. Input any text
2. Validate its length (min and max)
3. Display each letter as a char
4. if the user clicks on each one, it has to be deleted
class based components
 */

class TextMe extends Component{
    
    state = {
        myText: [],
    }

    //metodo para actualizar el contenido del textbox
    //se usa spreadOperator para no operar de manera directa el objeto
    updateTxtHandler = (event) => {
        //ejemplo de codigo mala practica y que no es ES6
        this.setState({
            myText: event.target.value,
        });
    }

    //funcion para borrar elementos de la lista
    deleteCharacterHandler = (deleteChar) => {
        console.log("La letra que deseo borrar es: "+deleteChar)

    }

    displayArrayContent = () => {
        const letters = [...this.state.myText];
        //iterar todos los elementos del arreglo
        letters.map((letter, index) => {
            console.log("item: " + letter + ", index: "+index)
        });
    }

    render(){  
        return(
            <div className="cajatipo1">
                <h1>Homework02: Text2Chars</h1>
                <div>
                    <h3>Please type any text you want</h3>
                    <input type="text" width="80" placeholder="Type any text greater than 3 characters"
                    value={this.state.myText}
                    onChange={this.updateTxtHandler}
                    />
                    <h3>Using "state" to update this control simultaneously:</h3>
                    <label>{this.state.myText}</label> 
                    {this.state.myText.length>0 ?
                        <p>
                            <ValidateText myTxtLength={this.state.myText.length} />
                            {this.state.myText.map((letter, index) => {
                                <CharText 
                                removeCharacter={() => this.deleteCharacterHandler(index)}
                                />
                            })}
                        </p>
                        : null
                    }
                </div>
            </div>    
        )
    }
}

export default TextMe;
```

So, my main problem is related to these lines:

```
<p>
  <ValidateText myTxtLength={this.state.myText.length} />
  {this.state.myText.map((letter, index) => {
        <CharText 
        removeCharacter={() => this.deleteCharacterHandler(index)}
       />
  })}
</p>
```

I've read a lot that this exception is thrown when the var is not an array and that's it,in my case, that var is "myText", at the beginning I defined it like this:

```
state = {
            myText: [],
        }
```

But still I'm getting the exception.My question is: what am I missing to avoid the TypeError exception?

Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running into the error since `this.state.myText` is a string. You can use `[...this.state.myText]` to create an array of the characters in the string. You might want to initialize the `myText` state variable to an empty string for clarity. The `input` field value is set to an empty string even though the initial value is `[]` since it gets converted to a string - `[].toString()` => `''`.

```
state = {
  myText: ''
}
```

And the other issue is that you're not returning the `CharText` component inside the callback passed to the [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method.

```
{
  [...this.state.myText].map((letter, index) => (
    <CharText removeCharacter={() => this.deleteCharacterHandler(index)} />
  ))
}
```

Comment: thank you for your comment, indeed, I'm not getting the TypeError anymore, however, the CharText component is not working anymore, I need a minute to figure out why is that. Again, thank you again for your detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting myText to an empty array with `myText: []`, but because JavaScript is not a typed language, you are setting it to a string here: `myText: event.target.value`

If you want to use map (or need to for this assignment) then you could split your string into an array of characters like this:

```
this.state.myText.split('').map((letter, index) => {...})
```

Don't forget that you need to return the CharText component.

Comment: thank you for your comment, indeed, I'm not getting the TypeError anymore, however, the CharText component is not working anymore, I need a minute to figure out why is that. Again, thank you for your time.